# Is good middot ldavka bo?

Tags: mitzvah, middos-character-traits

On one hand having good middot is the Mitzva of [holachta bdrachav](http://sefaria.org/Sefer_HaChinukh.611).
And the mitzvah of [ledavka bo](http://sefaria.org/Sefer_HaChinukh.434) is to connect to Talmidai chachomim

But I see that ledavka bo is also explained as having good middot ([Tanya](https://www.chabad.org/dailystudy/tanya.asp?tdate=9%2F2%2F2045) (the teaching of our Sages, of blessed memory, on the verse, “And to cleave unto Him”: “Cleave unto His attributes.”) and [Pele Yoetz](http://sefaria.org/Pele_Yoetz.58.2))

How/why did ledavka bo become the same as holachta bdrachav?